# Microsoft SSAS-Tabular Model: SSMS crashes after 90 seconds - EVALUATE 'LargeFactTable'

Tags: crash, ssms, dax, sql-server-2016, ssas-tabular

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2016, with Tabular Model (SSAS-TM) as the native instance of Analysis Services.

I developed a project in Visual Studio 2015 and deployed it in the SSAS-TM server.

I am able to query dimension tables easily using the SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

However, for large fact tables (about 5 M records), the following query crashes the SSMS, roughly about 90 seconds:

**EVALUATE 'LargeFactTable'**

I have installed all the necessary service packs, the latest being [SP3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103440) for SQL Server 2016, a cumulative release in Sep 2021.

Is there any memory setting that I should change ? May be in the SSMS properties for the Analysis Services Server.  Please let me know.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft    possible to  look at this ? thanks

Comment: Try with the latest SSMS download.  The one from SQL 2016 is pretty old. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: any other option possible, instead of a new installation, which is the last resort?

Comment: It’s a client tool.  You don’t need to install it on the server.

Comment: Could you try using the Export Data feature of DAX Studio to do this? I suspect SSMS is running up against the 1GB 32-bit process memory limit and isn’t really designed for rendering huge result sets. https://daxstudio.org/documentation/features/export-data/

Comment: @GregGalloway     ok; thanks very much for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would never EVALUATE more than 1000 rows in SSMS. It's not meant to be a client tool. Instead, use Power BI Desktop, or Excel if you must. If you want to report on more than a million rows in Excel, you either need a live connection or load the data to PowerPivot.

If the end result is that you are trying to export the data from SSAS, either use [DAX Studio](https://www.biinsight.com/exporting-data-from-power-bi-desktop-to-excel-and-csv-part-1-copy-paste-and-dax-studio-methods/) or [Excel VBA](https://www.powerpivotblog.nl/export-a-table-or-dax-query-from-power-pivot-to-csv-using-vba/).